# org mode Capture templates

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to know how to use the annotation, %A in the org-template.

```
 %a          Annotation, normally the link created with org-store-link.
 %A          Like %a, but prompt for the description part.
```

I was able to use %A but got something to get the following:

```
** TODO 
  To improve
  [[file:~/Documents/python/python/xml2csv.py::print%20elem.text,%20use.text][%^{Link description}]]
```

So I get a Link description as prompt but I don't know how to modify the prompt. *link description*. I wonder what should prompt the description part?

By contrast the regular prompt specify **Prompt the user**

```
 %^{prop}p   Prompt the user for a value for property prop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
("r" "Meeting Schedule" entry 
      (file+headline "~/org/your-file.org" "HEADING") 
      "* TODO Meeting - %? 
       %i
       Room: %^{Place}
       Subject of the Meeting: %^{Subject}
       Who will Atend: %^{Atendees}

 %a ")
```

I've mixed many uses, but if you want some string to prompt you you can use it likee `%^{Place}A` (it'll prompt you for Place, and use the rules of annotation.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I would like a prompt for the link associated with %a/. and A% do the job I want.